# Polyextremal groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, semigroups-and-monoids

A *polynomial* of a semigroup $X$ is a function $f:X\to X$ of the form
$f(x)=a_0xa_1\cdots xa_n$, where $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ some elements of the semigroup $X^1=X\cup\{1\}$, called the *coefficients* of the polynomial $f$. The number $n$ is called the *degree* of $f$ and is denoted by $\deg(f)$.

A subset $A$ of a semigroup $X$ is called *algebraic* if $A=\{x\in X:f(x)=b\}$ for some polynomial $f:X\to X$ and some $b\in X$.

**Example 1.** For any semigroup $X$ any singleton $\{b\}\subseteq X$ is an algebraic set as $\{b\}=\{x\in X:1x1=b\}$.

**Example 2.** For any group $X$ of finite exponent $\exp(X)=\min\{n\in\mathbb N:\forall x\in X\;(x^n=1)\}$, the set $X=\{x\in X:x^n=1\}$ is algebraic.

**Example 3.** Let $n\ge 3$ be an odd number, and $a$ and $b$ be two elements of order $n$ and $2$ in the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ (of isometries of a regular $n$-gon). For the polynomials $f(x)=bxxbxx$ and $g(x)=a^{-1}xaxxaxa^{-1}$ of degree 4 we have $f^{-1}(1)=X$ and $g^{-1}(1)=\{1\}$.

**Definition.** Let us call a group $X$ *polyextremal* if $X$ has two polynomials $f,g:X\to X$ such that $$\deg(f)=\deg(g),\quad f^{-1}(1)=X\quad\mbox{and}\quad g^{-1}(1)=\{1\}.$$

Example 3 shows that for every odd number $n\ge 3$, the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is polyextremal.

> **Problem 1.** Characterize polyextremal finite groups.

**Remark 1.** Each polyextremal group $X$ has trivial center $Z(X)=\{z\in X:\forall x\in X\;(zx=xz)\}$. Indeed, assuming that $f,g:X\to X$ are two polynomials with $\deg(f)=\deg(g)$, $f^{-1}(1)=X$, $g^{-1}(1)=\{1\}$, we can see that
$$f(z)=f(1)z^{\deg(f)}=z^{\deg(f)}=z^{\deg(g)}=g(1)z^{\deg(g)}=g(z)$$ for all $z\in Z(X)$ and hence $Z(X)=\{1\}$.

**Remark 2.** Remark 1 implies that for a number $n\ge 2$ the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is polyextremal if and only if $n$ is odd.

> **Problem 2.** Is each finite group with trivial center polyextremal?

> **Problem 3.** Is each noncommutative finite simple group polyextremal?

Comment: In the definition of polynomial and Example 1, you seem to assume that semigroups have a unit, i.e., are monoids.

Comment: A function $X\to X$ might be represented as polynomials of several degrees. In the definition of polyextremal, are you quantifying on polynomials or on function (where $\deg(f)$ should be the least degree of a polynomial representing $f$)?

Comment: @YCor The unit 1 is attached to a semigroup if it does not contain the unit. So, I wrote that $a_i\in X^1=X\cup\{1\}$. This is a standard practice in the semigroup theory.

Comment: @YCor In the definition of polyextremal I quantify over polynomials (not functions represented by polynomials). So, I have $n+1$ places for coefficients and chainging those coefficient would like to have quite different polynomials of degree $n$ (for some purposes, like in this question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/428777/61536).